# How to check if a string contains chars that are outside of a given char list

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string, and I need to check if this string contains any chars that are not in a given list.

Suppose i have this allowed chars `new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' , '.'}`

If string is "54323.5" - this will be ok !

If string is "543g23.5" - this won't be ok since it contains "g" which is not in the list of my allowed chars.

An empty string is considered invalid.

I am trying to achieve this by using  "IndexOfAny()" but with no luck so far. Of course passing all the unallowed chars to this method won't be a solution.

Please note that the list of the allowed chars may change and changing the validation algorithm based on the list change is not considered a solution.

For you guys that asked me the code that I tried, here it is:

```
        private bool CheckInvalidInput(string stringToCheck)
    {
        char[] allowedChars = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

        var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, char.MaxValue + 1)
                  .Select(i => (char)i)
                  .ToArray();

        var unallowedChars = chars.Except(allowedChars).ToArray();

        bool validString = true;
        if(stringToCheck.IndexOfAny(unallowedChars) != -1)
        {
            validString = false;
        }

        return validString;
    }
```

Hope that you will come with a better solution :D.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have tried

Comment: Use `Enumerable` extensión methods (`System.Linq`): `Any` and `Contains` will do the job if used smartly.

Comment: @Greg I posted the code that I tried, could you do it better ? And the others who upvoted for this. Not sure why someone down voted the question.

Comment: just do it - foreach (char in testString) with inner foreach (char in allowed chars). if you need performance - first make array of bool of 64k with chars as indexes, then foreach (char in testString) and check allowance across that array - you will have O(N)

Comment: @Lanorkin your suggestion sounds really good I will try it like that, and also with the suggested regular expression approach from below, the solution with less code will win :).

Comment: This is the template `^(?=.)\d*\.?\d*$`for max 1 optional period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straightforward to achieve. The `string` type implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can use the LINQ `All` method to check that all its characters satisfy a predicate. In your case, the predicate is that each character is contained in the `allowedChars` set, so you can use the `Contains` method:

```
private static bool CheckInvalidInput(string stringToCheck, IEnumerable<char> allowedChars)
{
    return stringToCheck.All(allowedChars.Contains);
}
```

If your `allowedChars` set gets large, you would want to convert it to a `HashSet<char>` for better performance.

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // var allowedChars = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.' };
        var allowedChars = "0123456789.";

        Console.WriteLine(CheckInvalidInput("54323.5", allowedChars));   // True
        Console.WriteLine(CheckInvalidInput("543g23.5", allowedChars));  // False
    }

    private static bool CheckInvalidInput(string stringToCheck, IEnumerable<char> allowedChars)
    {
        return stringToCheck.All(allowedChars.Contains);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a very simple pattern. `Regex.IsMatch(yourString, @"^[\d.]+$");`

`^` is the beginning of the line

`[\d.]+` matches one or more characters (either `.` or `0-9`)

`$` is the end of the line

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPKQz3/1)

Edit: This will also match `.`

If this behavior is not intended, then try using this [`^(?=\d)[\d.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/BPKQz3/2)

Comment: Hi, yes this is gonna work fine for the sets of chars that I gave in the example but the list of the allowed chars may change so that it contains numbers let's say and some other chars like "-" , "/"  and others.

Comment: So if you need to add any other acceptable characters, just put them in between the square brackets like so: `[\d.\-/]`

Comment: Your suggestion will sure work but I will have to change the regular expression every time I change the "allowed" list of chars, this is something that is "extra". I would like to change only the list of the "allowed" chars and use the same lets say regular expression or validation algorithm to check if my input is OK.

Comment: So save the original regex pattern as a string, then when you know which symbols you need to include, add them to the string using `pattern.Insert(pattern.IndexOf("[" + 1), symbolsToAdd);` where `symbolsToAdd` is something like "$%^&"

Comment: You tagged this question with regex, but using a character array is not a regex solution

Answer (score 1):

If an array of allowed chars is dynamic, you can create procedure which would accept an array of allowed chars and construct pattern on the fly. Please, note that you have to escape certain chars in order to use in Regex:

```
static void TestRegex(char[] check_chars)
{
    string[] inputs = { "54323.5", "543g23.5" };
    var check_chars2 = check_chars.Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString()));
    string pattern = "^(" + string.Join("|", check_chars2) + ")+$";
    foreach (string input in inputs)
    {
        WriteLine($"Input {input} does{(Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern) ? "" : " not")} match");
    }
}

// Output:
// Input 54323.5 does match
// Input 543g23.5 does not match
```